# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am getting the following code which tries to save DataFrame to provided path

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet("/path/year=2018")
```

I get the following exception when I use above code. I am using Spark 2.2.0. I am new to Spark.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:270)
    at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:189)
    at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87) at
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108) at
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338) at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 

Caused by:  java.lang.NullPointerException at
        org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkSession.scala:468)
        at
        org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkSession.scala:468)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409) at
        scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409) at
        org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:324)
        at
        org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
        at
        org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:254)
        at
        org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1371)
        at
        org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:259)
```

Comment: can you check df.show() before you write the data ?

Comment: Did you drop the `year` column?